# folder path in Program arguments is missing the last '/' in sts4

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-tool-suite

in `Run Configurations`-> `Arguments`->  `Program arguments`, I have a folder path `D:\testPicFolder\`. But in the main method:

```
imgPath=args[0];
```

imgPath is always `D:\testPicFolder` , which is missing the last `\`.

How can I fix this?

---------------update:

If I use `D:/testPicFolder/`, it works fine.
But I use `D:\testPicFolder\` since `\` works both for Windows and Linux.

Comment: Add it as `"D:\testPicFolder\\"`.

Comment: @howlger that does not work.

Comment: It works for me in Eclipse 2020-12.